# no matching constructor error when resize a vector

Tags: c++, vector

If anyone have any good ideas, it will be great. Post code and error message below,

**Source code**,

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(const string& name, double score);
  Foo(const Foo& other);
  Foo(Foo&& other);
  const string& name() const { return name_; }
  double score() const { return score_; }
 private:
  string name_;
  double score_;
};

Foo::Foo(const string& name, double score)
    : name_(name), score_(score) {}


Foo::Foo(
    const Foo& other) {
  name_ = other.name();
  score_ = other.score();
}

Foo::Foo(Foo&& other)
    : name_(std::move(other.name())), score_(std::move(other.score())) {}

  std::vector<Foo> students;
  students.emplace_back("name1", 1.0);
  students.emplace_back("name2", 2.0);
  students.resize(1);
```

**Error message**,

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'Foo'
    { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Comment: `string name_;` Why the underscore?

Comment: You don't have a default constructor. When you resize to 1, that 1 element will be default constructed.

Comment: Pop quiz for you: when you attempt to do a plain `resize()`, which constructor gets used to construct all the new elements in the now-bigger vector? Everything that exists, in the C++ world, must be constructed, so all the new elements in the now-bigger vector have to be constructed. So, which constructor gets used, for them? Think about it, then read the duplicate question.

Comment: @gchen could you elaborate a bit more why need default constructor? Still miss your points. I am thinking when resize, why the 1 element cannot be copy assignment constructed?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I thought copy constructor is used, please correct me if I am wrong. And I already provided copy constructor.

Comment: That’s the rule when you call resize with just a size argument, and it wouldn’t make sense to call the copy constructor - which object should it copy from?

Comment: If you call resize(num, aFooObject), it will indeed use the copy constructor. See the duplicated question attached, or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: If your vector contains 5 elements, and you call `resize(8)`, which copy constructor do you expect to be called??? There are five elements in the vector, do you expect the vector to pick one of the five existing values, randomly, and use its copy constructor to create the three new elements? That makes no sense, whatsoever. A copy constructor copies a ***specific*** instance of an object, not a randomly chosen one. Think about it.